# php Postgresql pg_query(): duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: php, postgresql, joomla, phpunit, joomla-framework

We are working on refactoring our Framework Postgresql driver to allow for transactions. In the process, we have introduced some issues resulting in the following error

`pg_query(): duplicate key value violates unique constraint DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists`

link to travis test with some more details
https://travis-ci.org/photodude/database/jobs/175596877

The relevant portion of the driver having issues is at this link

https://github.com/joomla-framework/database/blob/master/src/Postgresql/PostgresqlDriver.php#L711-L819

The related test(s) with the issue is

https://github.com/joomla-framework/database/blob/master/Tests/DriverPostgresqlTest.php#L1116-L1163

I get that the table sequence is somehow messed up, but I'm at a loss on why the table sequence is messed up or even just how to fix the code so the tests function correctly.

note: I believe this failure is related to prepared and unprepared statements

Answer (score 0):

At line 519 restarting sequence and truncate table which looks ok, but if that runs inside a rollbacked transaction, truncate will not happen, but sequence restart [will](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html)

> ```
>     Important: Because sequences are non-transactional, changes made by setval are not undone if the transaction rolls back.
> ```

see:

```
s1=> create table test1 ( id serial primary key, a text not null);
CREATE TABLE
s1=> \d
             List of relations
 Schema |     Name     |   Type   | Owner  
--------+--------------+----------+--------
 public | test1        | table    | albert
 public | test1_id_seq | sequence | albert
(2 rows)

s1=> insert into test1(a) values ('apple');
INSERT 0 1
s1=> select * from test1;
 id |   a   
----+-------
  1 | apple
(1 row)

s1=> select * from test1_id_seq;
 sequence_name | last_value | start_value | increment_by |      max_value      | min_value | cache_value | log_cnt | is_cycled | is_called 
---------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------
 test1_id_seq  |          1 |           1 |            1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 |           1 |      32 | f         | t
(1 row)

s1=> insert into test1(a) values ('bannana');
INSERT 0 1
s1=> select * from test1;
 id |    a    
----+---------
  1 | apple
  2 | bannana
(2 rows)

s1=> insert into test1(a) values ('bannana');
INSERT 0 1
s1=> select * from test1;
 id |    a    
----+---------
  1 | apple
  2 | bannana
  3 | bannana
(3 rows)

s1=> select * from test1_id_seq;
 sequence_name | last_value | start_value | increment_by |      max_value      | min_value | cache_value | log_cnt | is_cycled | is_called 
---------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------
 test1_id_seq  |          3 |           1 |            1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 |           1 |      30 | f         | t
(1 row)

s1=> begin;
BEGIN
s1=> alter sequence test1_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
ALTER SEQUENCE
s1=> truncate table test1;
TRUNCATE TABLE
s1=> rollback;
ROLLBACK
s1=> select * from test1_id_seq;
 sequence_name | last_value | start_value | increment_by |      max_value      | min_value | cache_value | log_cnt | is_cycled | is_called 
---------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------
 test1_id_seq  |          1 |           1 |            1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 |           1 |       0 | f         | f
(1 row)

s1=> select * from test1;
 id |    a    
----+---------
  1 | apple
  2 | bannana
  3 | bannana
(3 rows)

s1=>
```

Comment: The same is true of `TRUNCATE ... RESTART IDENTITY`.

Comment: That's an interesting note. I'm not sure it applies to the specific failure here though. Isolating the tests I still get the failure. This seems to be related to using prepared statements since in running just the execute tests we are not using transactions.

Answer (score 0):

We are still not sure of the root cause but the whole issue is related to the unit tests. something is/was globally restarting the table sequence even when just the one failing test was checked. We found a way around the issue but are still looking for the root cause.

We also found we needed to improve the tearDown() methods for all the driver tests.